# Is this inequality on Schatten p-norm $\|AB\|_{S_p} \le \|A\|_{S_p}\|B\|_{S_p}$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

The Schatten-$p$ norm ($p >0$) of a matrix $X$ is defined as

$\|X\|_{S_p} = (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i^p(X))^{1/p}$

Where $\sigma_i(X)$ denotes the $i$-th singular value of $X$

Is the follow inequalities true for any two matrices $A$ and $B$

$\|AB\|_{S_p}  \le  \|A\|_{S_p}\|B\|_{S_p}$

And how to proof? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the Schatten $p$-norm is only a norm when $p \geq 1$.

The inequality indeed holds for any matrices $A,B$ when $p \geq 1$.  To see that this is the case, it suffices to use the fact that 
$$
\sigma_i(AB) \leq \sigma_1(A) \sigma_i(B)
$$

Comment: So, the inequality holds for all $p>0$, right?

Comment: Cool, The $\sigma_1(A)$ is  $\sigma_i(A)$ in above.

Comment: @jason no, one of them needs to be $\sigma_1$